# Como retorna todas as linhas da consulta SQL com PHP?

Tags: php

O resultado que tenho da consulta SQL é este:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero retornar essas duas linhas da coluna 'publicacao'.Mas utilizando este código:

```
<?php  
  //Código para buscar os tweets do usuário
  $sqlTweets = "SELECT publicacao FROM tweets INNER JOIN usuarios ON  usuarios.id_usuario = tweets.id_usuario WHERE apelido_usuario = '{$usuario}' OR email = '{$usuario}'";
  $buscaTweets = mysqli_query( $link, $sqlTweets );

  if ( $buscaTweets ) {
    $tweets = mysqli_fetch_row( $buscaTweets );
  }
?>
```

É retornado um erro quando tento acessar o índice 1 de '$tweets', o erro é esse:
'Undefined offset: 1 in'. Ou seja só está me retornando a primeira linha da consulta e eu quero que seja retornada todas, como faço ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É importante entender o funcionamento de cada função. A função [mysqli_fetch_row](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php), como o manual informa:

> mysqli_result::fetch_row -- mysqli_fetch_row — Get a result row as an
>   enumerated array

Retorna uma linha de resultado (da consulta/query) como um array enumerado.

Sendo sua consulta de apenas uma coluna, o resultado deve ser similar a este:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "teste_sql" }
```

Por isso que ao acessar o índice 1 ocorre um erro. Ele não existe, pois, existe apenas uma **coluna** como resultado da consulta.

Ainda, conforme o manual:

> Fetches one row of data from the result set and returns it as an
>   enumerated array, where each column is stored in an array offset
>   starting from 0 (zero). **Each subsequent call to this function will
>   return the next row within the result set, or NULL if there are no
>   more rows.**

Cada consulta subsequente irá retornar o próximo resultado, ou NULL caso não existam mais linhas. Logo, você pode utilizar `while` para retornar todos os resultados:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($buscaTweets))
{
    printf('Resultado: %s' , $row[0]);
}
```

E, desta forma, você irá *iterar* sobre todos os resultados da consulta.

Outra forma, seria utilizar a função [mysqli_fetch_all](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php). Diferente de [mysqli_fetch_row](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php), ela irá retornar um array com todos os resultados do banco de dados:

```
$resultArray = mysqli_fetch_all($buscaTweets);

foreach($resultArray as $row)
{
    printf('Resultado: %s' , $row[0]);
}
```